# How to check an AWS S3 key for existence with the AWS CPP SDK?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-cpp

I use the **S3 SDK CPP** and have the following cenario:

1. I get some information sent from a client to my server (client wants to download from *S3*)
2. With the information sent I create a *S3* key
3. I want to check if the key exists (has a file) on the *S3*
4. I create a presigned URL that allows the client to download a file from *S3*
5. Send URL to client
6. Client downloads the file

Before I execute step 4 I want to check if the key really exists on the S3. The client can't download a file that does not exist anyway.

I have an `AWS::S3Client` object. Do I really need to create a *TransferManager* for this or is there a simple way to handle this with the client object?

The client itself does not have a relation to *S3* so I can't check it there. The server has to do all the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a working solution:

```
auto client = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::S3::S3Client>("client", getCredentials(), getClientConfig());
Aws::S3::Model::HeadObjectRequest request;
request.WithBucket(<bucketname>).WithKey(<s3key>);
const auto response = client->HeadObject(request);
response.IsSuccess(); //Is key existing on s3?
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue an authenticated HTTP HEAD request against the object. You can use:

- [HeadObject](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_s3_1_1_s3_client.html#a9a9262c4a4b825e9b85668cf2d607fe4)
- [HeadObjectAsync](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_s3_1_1_s3_client.html#aa0be15d5a4b0956e6ad51728b3482e13)

To quote:

> The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning
>   the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested
>   in an object's metadata. To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the
>   object.